# How do I attach an image to the reference frame in argon so that it moves with the camera wherever the user moves the phone to

Tags: image, aframe, hud, argon

How do I attach an image to the reference frame in argon so that it moves with the camera based wherever the user points the phone? Basically, I want it to be like a HUD, and in my case, it will just be a still image that I've designed in photoshop that I want to work like a map key.

I've tried the following based on some A-Frame documentation, but it doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't seem to alter the application at all. I put this within my ar-scene.

```
<ar-camera>
      <a-entity>

        <a-image src="#imgKey" width="4" height="2" scale="1 1 1" position="0 0 0">
        </a-image>

      </a-entity>
</ar-camera>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Will have to ask @blairmacintyre the ar-camera implementation. It would usually work with a normal camera, but might not with ar-camera. Maybe try defining a normal camera? Don't know.

Comment: I figured it out! It was a positioning issue. Here is the code that worked.

Comment: <a-entity position="0 0 5">

          <ar-camera>

              <a-image src="#imgKey" width="4" height="2" scale="1 1 1" position="0 0 -5"></a-image>

          </ar-camera>

      </a-entity>

Comment: Nice, you can post that as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that worked. Simply put this within the ar-scene. It was a positioning issue:

```
 <a-entity position="0 0 5">

      <ar-camera>

          <a-image src="#imgKey" width="4" height="2" scale="1 1 1" position="0 0 -5"></a-image>

      </ar-camera>

  </a-entity>
```